# AngularJS component binding through HTML attribute not working

Tags: angularjs

[image]

In the above screenshot you can see that when I am binding the `$ctrl.fieldOfView` controller variable to the `<image-selection>` component, the `$ctrl.fieldOfView` declaration is found by WebStorm and the `fov` attribute is allowed. But when I'm trying to bind the `$ctrl.fieldOfView` variable to the `<video-success>` component, the `fov` attribute is not allowed and the `$ctrl.fieldOfView` declaration is not found.

What is the difference between the two components?

Here's the component code:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    const templateUrl = 'app/target/dialogs/uploadObject/video-success/video-success.html';

    angular
        .module('component.target.video-success')
        .component('videoSuccess', {
            templateUrl,
            bindings: {
                fov: '=',
                hasUploadError: '<',
                uploadedFile: '<',
                resetUpload: '&'
            },
            controller: class VideoSuccessComponent {

                static $inject: string[] = [];

                constructor() {
                }
            }
        });
})();
```

Comment: Did video-success component has fov attribute ?

Comment: yes, I added the component code to the question

Comment: Your code looks right . For try replace "=" with "<" . Check binding on $onChanges. And Do not use '=' two-way data binding syntax anymore, anywhere.

Comment: How would I communicate with the parent controller, that the fov binding changed? By calling a bound method on the $onChanges event?

Comment: In videoSuccess component use $onChanges(changes){ changes.fov}; Inspect this line. it will help.

Comment: But this would only inform me if fov changed on the parent - but if I am changing it in the <video-success> component I would also like to update it on the parent controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165477/discussion-between-himanshu-shekhar-and-markus-torok).